# Python: How to read csv file with different separators?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

This is the first line of my txt.file

```
0.112296E+02-.121994E-010.158164E-030.158164E-030.000000E+000.340000E+030.328301E-010.000000E+00
```

There should be 8 columns, sometimes separated with '-', sometimes with '.'. It's very confusing, I just have to work with the file, I didn't generate it.

And second question: How can I work with the different columns? There is no header, so maybe:

`df.iloc[:,0]` .. ?

Comment: there is **no** csv writer that would produce a document like that. so it would have to be typed in. Also, it does not look like the `-` and `.` are separators. can it not be that `-` is just a negative number and `.` the decimal? in that case, there would be no separator rather a certain, fixed width. In your case 12 digits long (1.12E+01 , -1.22E-02 , 1.58E-04 , 1.58E-04 , 0.00E+00 , 3.40E+02 , 3.28E-02 , 0.00E+00)

Comment: it's not generated from a csv writer. It's from an Ansys code I didn't write. yes, '-' is the negativ exponent for e and '.' is the decimal. How can I do it, regardlessly?

Comment: That line seems to be bad enough for a human to parse! The whole line is data; there are no definite boundaries or delimiters defined.

Comment: Yes I know, but I need to work with it and have no idea how?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in comments, this is likely a list of numbers in scientific notation, that aren't separated by anything but simply glued together.
It could be interpreted as:

```
0.112296E+02
-.121994E-010
.158164E-030
.158164E-030
.000000E+000
.340000E+030
.328301E-010
.000000E+00
```

or as

```
0.112296E+02
-.121994E-01
0.158164E-03
0.158164E-03
0.000000E+00
0.340000E+03
0.328301E-01
0.000000E+00
```

Assuming the second interpretation is better, the trick is to split evenly every 12 characters.

```
data = [line[i:i+12] for i in range(0, len(line), 12)]
```

If really the first interpretation is better, then I'd use a REGEX

```
import re
line = '0.112296E+02-.121994E-010.158164E-030.158164E-030.000000E+000.340000E+030.328301E-010.000000E+00'
pattern = '[+-]?\d??\.\d+E[+-]\d+'
data = re.findall(pattern, line)
```

---

**Edit**

Obviously, you'd need to iterate over each line in the file, and add it to your dataframe. This is a rather inefficient thing to do in Pandas. Therefore, if your preferred interpretation is the fixed width one, I'd go with @Ev. Kounis ' answer: `df = pd.read_fwf(myfile, widths=[12]*8)`

Otherwise, the inefficient way is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(8))
with open(myfile, 'r') as f_in:
    for i, lines in enumerate(f_in):
        data = re.findall(pattern, line)
        df.loc[i] = [float(d) for d in data]
```

The two things to notice here is that the DataFrame must be initialized with column names (here [0, 1, 2, 3..7] but perhaps you know of better identifiers); and that the regex gave us strings that must be casted to floats.

Comment: after the `E` comes the sign and after that only 2 digits. Thisi is important since `'-.121994E-010'` and `'-.121994E-01'` don't convert to the same float. So yes, the second interpretation is better but you are printing the first, right?

Comment: You can use `\d{2}` instead of `\d+` at the end to make the regex capture the second form.

Comment: The first solution seems to work pretty great. But how can I do it if my file contains more than one row? I need the solution column-wise

Comment: I extended my answer, but this starts to be outside the scope of the initial question :-) (search for other QA)

Answer (score 3):

As i said in the comments, it is not a case of multiple separators, it is just a fixed width format. `Pandas` has a method to read such files. try this:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(myfile, widths=[12]*8)
print(df)  # prints -> [0.112296E+02, -.121994E-01, 0.158164E-03, 0.158164E-03.1, 0.000000E+00, 0.340000E+03, 0.328301E-01, 0.000000E+00.1]
```

for the widths you have to provide the cell width which looks like its *12* and the number of columns which as you say must be *8*.

As you might notice the results of the read are not perfect (notice the `.1` just before the comma in the 4th and last element) but i am working on it.

---

Alternatively, you can do it *"manually"* like so:

```
myfile = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\PythonScripts\a_file.csv'
width = 12
my_content = []
with open(myfile, 'r') as f_in:
    for lines in f_in:
        data = [float(lines[i * width:(i + 1) * width]) for i in range(len(lines) // width)]
        my_content.append(data)
print(my_content)  # prints -> [[11.2296, -0.0121994, 0.000158164, 0.000158164, 0.0, 340.0, 0.0328301, 0.0]]
```

and every row would be a nested list.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is the following:

```
row = '0.112296E+02-.121994E-010.158164E-030.158164E-030.000000E+000.340000E+030.328301E-010.000000E+00'
chunckLen = 12
for i in range(0, len(row), chunckLen):
    print(row[0+i:chunckLen+i])
```

You can easly extend the code to handle more general cases.